# Usar ProgressBar em cópia de pastas e seus conteúdos

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

Tenho uma aplicação em C# WinForms que ao clicar em um botão, deve iniciar a cópia de várias pastas e seus respectivos conteúdos.

Como este processo é demorado, gostaria de que o usuário soubesse como vai o andamento do processo através de uma `ProgressBar`.

Já achei alguns exemplos na internet que exemplificam um processo demorado usando uma repetição de `Thread.Sleep(10)`, mas não consigo aplicar este tipo de exemplo ao meu projeto.

Qual é a melhor forma de fazer? Pegar o número de pastas e implementar o `ProgressBar` conforme as pastas vão sendo copiadas?

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Voce tem que usar uma thread para que isso funcione.

A cada diretório copiado dentro do laço, execute esse comando:

```
BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    progressBar.Value = ((100 * contador) / diretorios.Count).ToString();
});
```

Ficaria algo assim:

```
int contador = 0;
foreach (var diretorio in diretorios)
{
    CopiarDiretorio();

    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        progressBar.Value = ((100 * contador) / diretorios.Count).ToString();
    });

    contador++;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Heverson! Me ajudou muito :)

Comment: Aceite a resposta @CristianQuadros

Comment: Falou @CristianQuadros!

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é usar o [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){
...
    foreach (FileInfo f in files)
    {
       f.CopyTo(destino);
       progresso++;
       backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progresso * 100 / files.Lenght);
    }
....
}


private void backgroundWorkerTransmitir_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e){
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```